# Best Questions & Answers from 3rd Quarter of 2017

Tags: discussion, best-of

This post is a continuation of the [grand](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/676/17) old [tradition](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/785/17) of gathering collections of particularly good Literature Q&A, so that we have some easily available links to show off to people.

Now that Literature has a [community-run Twitter account](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/689/17), one obvious use for this post will be to gather links for tweeting. But it's also useful for any kind of site promotion - if we want to show off the site to literary friends, it'll be much easier if we have a list of particularly great posts to point to.

> **Please nominate some exemplary Q&A from the third quarter (Jul/Aug/Sep) of 2017**.

- When choosing nominations, please remember the primary purpose: to showcase our site to people elsewhere in the hope of maybe tempting them to come here. Let's try to focus mainly on **great questions with great answers**, and perhaps also **great unanswered questions** (which we can advertise as "hey, why not come and answer this"), but *not* anything with subpar answers, which will tend to give a bad impression and defeat the purpose.
- Remember that **votes don't necessarily reflect quality**, and the purpose of this is to promote quality over score. Highly-voted posts are easy to find, underappreciated gems less so.
- Getting a wide range of different stories represented in our list here would also be nice, but not strictly necessary - feel free to nominate a bunch of Q&A about the same book, if you think they're all outstanding. But don't nominate questions just because they're about your favourite book.
- Multiple nominated posts per answer here is fine.
- Feel free to nominate either some of your own posts which you're particularly proud of, or posts from other people which really impressed you.
- Ideally, some explanation of *why* the nominated questions and answers are so good would be useful - constructive feedback might give people ideas about what to aim for in the future.

Answer (score 2):

I was sad that this question had no answers, so I poked around among [the questions and answers posted during the third quarter of 2017](https://literature.stackexchange.com/search?q=created%3A2017%E2%80%9307-01..2017-09-30) to see which ones I liked. Voilà:

### Question

- Matt Thrower's question about [the intended audience for the *Just Wm* stories](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/2915/289) was first an eyebrow raiser, then an eye-opener. I had not realized that they were ever meant to be anything other than children's stories. My sister, who's rather older than I, used to enjoy them as a girl, but by the time I was old enough to read them on my own they were passé.

### Both the question and associated answer

- Alex Doe's [interesting question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/3680/289) is about a particular rhetorical device that doesn't seem common in English: using a single word to combine two distinct grammatical constructions. Tsundoku's [excellent answer](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/3681/289) gives the German term for this kind of construction where it apparently is at least common enough to be identifiable by name.

### Answers

- Matt Thrower's [explanation](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/3063/289) of the phrase "the myth of fingerprints" was very useful and, as with all his posts, excellently argued.
- Another noteworthy answer from Matt was [this one](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/3584/289) about the historical battle to which Wilfred Owen's "Spring Offensive" refers.
- A rather poor question asking whether Shakespeare's plays were exclusively in iambic pentameter received three answers: one adequate, one good, and one first-rate. [Peter Shor's answer](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/3200/289) takes the actual yes/no aspect of the question for granted, relying on the other two answers for that. But his explanation of Shakespeare's metrical skill in varying iambic pentameter pushes the question in a fresh direction. I disagree with his scansion of two of the lines (for example, I don't believe "and" is stressed in "Tomorrow and tomorrow and tomorrow") but I like what he's done with the question.

Comment: Thanks for nominating my answer about the deer epitaph. Strictly speaking, it was posted in the [fourth quarter of 2020](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1508/2191), though.

Comment: @Tsundoku oops. Edited.