# Best Questions & Answers from 4th Quarter of 2017

Tags: discussion, best-of

Despite the failure of the [last](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/912/17), here's yet another in the [grand](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/676/17) old [tradition](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/785/17) of gathering collections of particularly good Literature Q&A so that we have some easily available links to show off to people.

Now that Literature has a [community-run Twitter account](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/689/17), one obvious use for this post will be to gather links for tweeting. But it's also useful for any kind of site promotion - if we want to show off the site to literary friends, it'll be much easier if we have a list of particularly great posts to point to.

> **Please nominate some exemplary Q&A from the fourth quarter (Oct/Nov/Dec) of 2017**.

- When choosing nominations, please remember the primary purpose: to showcase our site to people elsewhere in the hope of maybe tempting them to come here. Let's try to focus mainly on **great questions with great answers**, and perhaps also **great unanswered questions** (which we can advertise as "hey, why not come and answer this"), but *not* anything with subpar answers, which will tend to give a bad impression and defeat the purpose.
- Remember that **votes don't necessarily reflect quality**, and the purpose of this is to promote quality over score. Highly-voted posts are easy to find, underappreciated gems less so.
- Getting a wide range of different stories represented in our list here would also be nice, but not strictly necessary - feel free to nominate a bunch of Q&A about the same book, if you think they're all outstanding. But don't nominate questions just because they're about your favourite book.
- Multiple nominated posts per answer here is fine.
- Feel free to nominate either some of your own posts which you're particularly proud of, or posts from other people which really impressed you.
- Ideally, some explanation of *why* the nominated questions and answers are so good would be useful - constructive feedback might give people ideas about what to aim for in the future.

Answer (score 7):

I'm also nominating Rand al'Thor's answer to the question [When did the Rupert Bear stories start repeating themselves?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/2382/2191) because the exhaustive analysis it is based on: an examination of the "raw data in the form of all titles of all Rupert stories since the start of modern Rupert in 1936".

Comment: Aww, thank you :-) *blush*

Answer (score 4):

Shameless plug: [my answer to the question 'How many of Shakespeare's words in his plays were new?'](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/4714/2191). According to a comment on the answer, it is "well researched" and "even helped to define the scope of the question" :-)

Answer (score 4):

New member S.Bailey has a trio of excellent answers: [What's the significance of the stanza about V for victory in Tony Harrison's V?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/3960/whats-the-significance-of-the-stanza-about-v-for-victory-in-tony-harrisons-v), [Why don't modern critics like archetypes?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/3560/why-dont-modern-critics-like-archetypes/), and [Do authors who translate their own works tend to do accurate translations?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/3741/do-authors-who-translate-their-own-works-tend-to-do-accurate-translations/). New member jiaminglimjm had an excellent addition to an excellent question at [Language in A View from the Bridge](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/4168/111).

Answer (score 4):

We had some new users starting to contribute to the site in the 4th quarter of 2017 who provided some really good and well-researched answers (and questions too, in some cases). I'm listing some of the best answers from the ones who sprang to mind immediately. Nothing is implied about anyone who's not included in this list :-)

### Christophe Strobbe

As well as providing a great many tag wiki excerpts for the site (and thus preventing a lot of tags from being automatically removed from the system), this user has written some great answers:

- [Do Guildenstern and Rosencrantz deserve to die?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/5177/17)
- [How many of Shakespeare's words in his plays were new?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/4714/17)
- [Why doesn't Hamlet like improvisation?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/4101/17)
- [Why do the witches in Macbeth rarely speak in iambic pentameter?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/4700/17)

He's also posted some well-researched expert-level *questions*:

- [First English Renaissance play where women disguise as men?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/5105/17)
- [How many manuscripts of English Renaissance plays have survived?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/4954/17)

### Fabjaja

Many of this user's best answers are from 2018, but they joined the site in the last quarter of 2017 and posted some good stuff in this period too:

- [Did Thomas Hardy's books get more miserable with time, and was this because of his own life?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/4280/17)
- [What is the effect of a text written in present tense and first-person?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/4966/17)
- [What is the narrative device that involves using inconsequential elements in the story?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/5114/17)
- [Why do the witches in Macbeth rarely speak in iambic pentameter?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/4701/17)

### S.Bailey

As already mentioned by Hamlet/user111, this new user provided some excellent answers to general (not story-specific) questions, and one about a poem that's one of their particular areas of expertise:

- [Why don't modern critics like archetypes?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/3914/17)
- [Do authors who translate their own works tend to do accurate translations?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/3911/17)
- [How do I concentrate while reading a book?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/3913/17)
- [What's the significance of the stanza about V for victory in Tony Harrison's V?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/3981/17)

Comment: Ooh, this was the 1000th post on [meta.literature.se]!