# Best Questions & Answers from 2nd Quarter of 2018

Tags: discussion, best-of

Rather late, but here's another in [what's](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/989/17) now [becoming](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/912/17) a [grand](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/676/17) old [tradition](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/785/17) of [gathering](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1016/17) collections of particularly good Literature Q&A in order to get some easily available links to show off to people.

Now that Literature has a [community-run Twitter account](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/689/17), one obvious use for this post will be to gather links for tweeting. But it's also useful for any kind of site promotion - if we want to show off the site to literary friends, it'll be much easier if we have a list of particularly great posts to point to.

> **Please nominate some exemplary Q&A from the second quarter (Apr/May/Jun) of 2018**.

- When choosing nominations, please remember the primary purpose: to showcase our site to people elsewhere in the hope of maybe tempting them to come here. Let's try to focus mainly on **great questions with great answers**, and perhaps also **great unanswered questions** (which we can advertise as "hey, why not come and answer this"), but *not* anything with subpar answers, which will tend to give a bad impression and defeat the purpose.
- Remember that **votes don't necessarily reflect quality**, and the purpose of this is to promote quality over score. Highly-voted posts are easy to find, underappreciated gems less so.
- Getting a wide range of different stories represented in our list here would also be nice, but not strictly necessary - feel free to nominate a bunch of Q&A about the same book, if you think they're all outstanding. But don't nominate questions just because they're about your favourite book.
- Multiple nominated posts per answer here is fine.
- Feel free to nominate either some of your own posts which you're particularly proud of, or posts from other people which really impressed you.
- Ideally, some explanation of *why* the nominated questions and answers are so good would be useful - constructive feedback might give people ideas about what to aim for in the future.

Answer (score 2):

I'm nominating Christopher Lyons's answer to the question [Earliest work of fiction in which characters using telepathy can't lie](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/6825/2191). It's a well-informed answer, even though it is not definitive.