# Best Questions & Answers from 4th Quarter of 2018

Tags: discussion, best-of

Pretty late - sorry about that! - but this is the latest installment in [what's](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/676/17) now [becoming](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/785/17) a [grand](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/912/17) old [tradition](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/989/17) of [gathering](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1016/17) some [particularly](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1076/17) good [Literature](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1084/17) Q&A in order to get some easily available links to show off to people.

Since Literature has a [community-run Twitter account](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/689/17), one use for this post will be to gather links for tweeting. But it's also useful for any kind of site promotion - if we want to show off the site to literary friends, it'll be much easier if we have a list of particularly great posts to point to.

> **Please nominate some exemplary Q&A from the fourth quarter (Oct/Nov/Dec) of 2018**.

- When choosing nominations, please remember the primary purpose: to showcase our site to people elsewhere in the hope of maybe tempting them to come here. Let's try to focus mainly on **great questions with great answers**, and perhaps also **great unanswered questions** (which we can advertise as "hey, why not come and answer this") - *not* anything with subpar answers, which will tend to give a bad impression and defeat the purpose.
- Remember that **votes don't necessarily reflect quality**, and the purpose of this is to promote quality over score. Highly-voted posts are easy to find, underappreciated gems less so.
- Getting a wide range of different stories represented in our list here would also be nice, but not strictly necessary - feel free to nominate a bunch of Q&A about the same book, if you think they're all outstanding. But don't nominate questions just because they're about your favourite book.
- Multiple nominated posts per answer here is fine.
- Feel free to nominate either some of your own posts which you're particularly proud of, or posts from other people which really impressed you.
- Ideally, some explanation of *why* the nominated questions and answers are so good would be useful - constructive feedback might give people ideas about what to aim for in the future.

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend:

- andejons’ [thorough trawl](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/8544/3003) for evidence of want of propriety in *Pride and Prejudice*.
- blanketyblank’s [astute analysis](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/8861/3003) of Orwell’s claims about English intellectuals.
- Matt Thrower’s insightful interpretations of ‘[The Dolphins](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/8790/3003)’ and ‘[The King of Harlem](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/8769/3003)’.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit chuffed about my answer to ["What a piece of work is man" - echo in The Lord of the Rings?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/8626/what-a-piece-of-work-is-man-echo-in-the-lord-of-the-rings/8641#8641) - it's certainly the best answer I've ever written on literature, not that that's saying much. (Apologies for nominating one of my own, but darned if I didn't put a bunch of time into it!) I absolutely love answering Tolkien questions, and it was particularly interesting to trawl through his letters for opinions on Shakespeare.

Answer (score -2):

## Answers.

- My first ever Story ID answer on any kind of SE! [English short story where a wife makes an investigation officer eat the murder weapon](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/8930/english-short-story-where-a-wife-makes-an-investigation-officer-eat-the-murder-w/8931#8931) Loved seeing how accesible story ID actually is! I tended to stay away from trying to answer them but it has actually been really fun! And heres a really [helpful guide on how to make a good story id answer by Jenayah over on SFF.SE's Meta.](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12291/how-to-find-a-story-id-answer/12294#12294)

## Questions.

- I believe I provided a *very* answerable question with this one and really enjoyed coming up with this. [Why is the book called Lorna Doone?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/8584/why-is-the-book-called-lorna-doone)
- I'd also like to mention @AnkitSharma for the amazing question which I already mentioned above [English short story where a wife makes an investigation officer eat the murder weapon](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/8930/english-short-story-where-a-wife-makes-an-investigation-officer-eat-the-murder-w/8931#8931) Thank you for introducing me to Story ID!

Comment: Thanks for the nomination on Rowling/Caspian, but (a) it's *far* from the best answer around, or even the best one I've written, in recent months - not much research went into it, and frankly it has more votes than it deserves - and more importantly (b) it's not from the 4th quarter of 2018, so not eligible here. Your Moby Dick question isn't eligible either.