# Best Questions & Answers from 3rd Quarter of 2019

Tags: discussion, best-of

So apparently I forgot this in October, due to too much other stuff going on on Stack Exchange.

Here's the latest installment in [what's](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/676/17) now [becoming](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/785/17) a [grand](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/912/17) old [tradition](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/989/17) of [gathering](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1016/17) some [particularly](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1076/17) good [Literature](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1084/17) Q&A in [order](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1124/17) to [get](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1152/17) some [easily](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1169/17) available links to show off to people.

Since Literature has a [community-run Twitter account](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/689/17), one use for this post will be to gather links for tweeting. But it's also useful for any kind of site promotion - if we want to show off the site to literary friends, it'll be much easier if we have a list of particularly great posts to point to.

> **Please nominate some exemplary Q&A from the third quarter (Jul/Aug/Sep) of 2019**.

(I know it's late for this, but better late than never, right? Maybe someone still remembers some great stuff from those months, or will find something on taking a look through the content from then.)

- When choosing nominations, please remember the primary purpose: to showcase our site to people elsewhere in the hope of maybe tempting them to come here. Let's try to focus mainly on **great questions with great answers**, and perhaps also **great unanswered questions** (which we can advertise as "hey, why not come and answer this") - *not* anything with subpar answers, which will tend to give a bad impression and defeat the purpose.
- Remember that **votes don't necessarily reflect quality**, and the purpose of this is to promote quality over score. Highly-voted posts are easy to find, underappreciated gems less so.
- Getting a wide range of different stories represented in our list here would also be nice, but not strictly necessary - feel free to nominate a bunch of Q&A about the same book, if you think they're all outstanding. But don't nominate questions just because they're about your favourite book.
- Multiple nominated posts per answer here is fine.
- Feel free to nominate either some of your own posts which you're particularly proud of, or posts from other people which really impressed you.
- Ideally, some explanation of *why* the nominated questions and answers are so good would be useful - constructive feedback might give people ideas about what to aim for in the future.

Answer (score 3):

I particularly liked Spagirl's [komprehensive klarifikation of Krazy Kat's klassikal references](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/11360/3003), which when fully explained turned out not to be entirely classical after all.

Comment: Thank you! It was a real journey digging into that one and I enjoyed the trip immensely. I remain frustrated over the 39 dum dimmins and would dearly love to see the actual strip in question.