# Best Questions & Answers from 2nd Quarter of 2020

Tags: discussion, best-of

Here's the latest installment in [what's](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/676/17) now [becoming](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/785/17) a [grand](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/912/17) old [tradition](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/989/17) of [gathering](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1016/17) some [particularly](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1076/17) good [Literature](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1084/17) Q&A in [order](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1124/17) to [get](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1152/17) some [easily](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1169/17) available [links](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1216/17) to [show](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1217/17) off to [people](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1226/17).

Since Literature has a [community-run Twitter account](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/689/17), one use for this post will be to gather links for tweeting. But it's also useful for any kind of site promotion - if we want to show off the site to literary friends, it'll be much easier if we have a list of particularly great posts to point to.

> **Please nominate some exemplary Q&A from the second quarter (Apr/May/Jun) of 2020**.

(Also, if you find anything from previous months, feel free to go and post answers on any of the older [best-of](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-of) posts linked above. The date of the meta answer doesn't matter - late entries are still more than welcome! - only the date of the post on main that's being nominated.)

- When choosing nominations, please remember the primary purpose: to showcase our site to people elsewhere in the hope of maybe tempting them to come here. Let's try to focus mainly on **great questions with great answers**, and perhaps also **great unanswered questions** (which we can advertise as "hey, why not come and answer this") - *not* anything with subpar answers, which will tend to give a bad impression and defeat the purpose.
- Remember that **votes don't necessarily reflect quality**, and the purpose of this is to promote quality over score. Highly-voted posts are easy to find, underappreciated gems less so.
- Getting a wide range of different stories represented in our list here would also be nice, but not strictly necessary - feel free to nominate a bunch of Q&A about the same book, if you think they're all outstanding. But don't nominate questions just because they're about your favourite book.
- Multiple nominated posts per answer here is fine.
- Feel free to nominate either some of your own posts which you're particularly proud of, or posts from other people which really impressed you.
- Ideally, some explanation of *why* the nominated questions and answers are so good would be useful - constructive feedback might give people ideas about what to aim for in the future.

Answer (score 2):

**Literature from different eras**

I enjoyed a couple of posts because of how they brought together literature from different eras of history:

- [Meaning of "the matrons are very Sabines" in Fitzstephen's description of London](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/14212/17) Asked on ELU in April and migrated here in May. As I said in my migration flag: *"our users would love the challenge of interpreting a passage in a 1000-year-old book about a 2000-year-old metaphor referring to a 3000-year-old semi-legendary event :-)"*
- ["The Apple Tree" ending and the meaning behind it](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/11033/17) An older question which I answered in May. Answering it properly involved reading and researching both a short story from 1916 AD and a play from 428 BC, and understanding both well enough to sketch out the connections and contrasts.

**Correcting misconceptions**

We also had a couple of posts this quarter which really add value to the internet by correcting some common misconceptions about certain short stories (who wrote them or where/when). *Disclaimer: I asked both of these, but both of the answers shine way beyond what I'd expected and they're what I'm really trying to promote here.*

- [When were the short stories of Malgudi Days published?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/13907/17) Wikipedia says *Malgudi Days* is a collection published in 1943 and re-published in 1982. In fact, there are two entirely different collections called *Malgudi Days*: one of 19 stories published in 1943, one of 32 stories published in 1982. The answer here from muru is providing the internet with correct information about these stories.
- [Which short stories are falsely attributed to Guy de Maupassant, and why?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/14259/17) Many English-language collections of Maupassant short stories include some which aren't really by Maupassant at all. Gareth Rees's answer seems to be the only full list of these and their true authors published online in English.

Answer (score 1):

I enjoyed reading some of Matt Thrower's answers to the following questions:

- [Why is Christopher Marlowe considered an atheist?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/13959/2191),
- [How did Shakespeare get away with staging witchcraft in his plays such as in Othello, Macbeth, or The Tempest?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/14301/2191)
- [How might Shakespeare have become familiar with Dante's work?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/13992/2191)