# Best Questions & Answers from 3rd Quarter of 2020

Tags: discussion, best-of

Here's the latest installment in [what's](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/676/17) now [becoming](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/785/17) a [grand](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/912/17) old [tradition](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/989/17) of [gathering](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1016/17) some [particularly](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1076/17) good [Literature](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1084/17) Q&A in [order](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1124/17) to [get](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1152/17) some [easily](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1169/17) available [links](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1216/17) to [show](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1217/17) off [to](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1226/17) people [online](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1328/17).

Since Literature has a [community-run Twitter account](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/689/17), one use for this post will be to gather links for tweeting. But it's also useful for any kind of site promotion - if we want to show off the site to literary friends, it'll be much easier if we have a list of particularly great posts to point to.

> **Please nominate some exemplary Q&A from the third quarter (Jul/Aug/Sep) of 2020**.

(Also, if you find anything from previous months, feel free to go and post answers on any of the older [best-of](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-of) posts linked above. The date of the meta answer doesn't matter - late entries are still more than welcome! - only the date of the post on main that's being nominated.)

- When choosing nominations, please remember the primary purpose: to showcase our site to people elsewhere in the hope of maybe tempting them to come here. Let's try to focus mainly on **great questions with great answers**, and perhaps also **great unanswered questions** (which we can advertise as "hey, why not come and answer this") - *not* anything with subpar answers, which will tend to give a bad impression and defeat the purpose.
- Remember that **votes don't necessarily reflect quality**, and the purpose of this is to promote quality over score. Highly-voted posts are easy to find, underappreciated gems less so.
- Getting a wide range of different stories represented in our list here would also be nice, but not strictly necessary - feel free to nominate a bunch of Q&A about the same book, if you think they're all outstanding. But don't nominate questions just because they're about your favourite book.
- Multiple nominated posts per answer here is fine.
- Feel free to nominate either some of your own posts which you're particularly proud of, or posts from other people which really impressed you.
- Ideally, some explanation of *why* the nominated questions and answers are so good would be useful - constructive feedback might give people ideas about what to aim for in the future.

Comment: Useful searches: [questions](https://literature.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=created%3a2020-07..2020-09%20is%3aq) and [answers](https://literature.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=created%3a2020-07..2020-09%20is%3aa) from 2020Q3 ordered by votes.

Answer (score 2):

Among contributions by new users, I appreciated [b4rtr's answer to the question about whether the Tsar's secret police searched the apartment of one of Dostoevsky's neighbours](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/15098/2191). This answer also cited sources in Russian, which is something we don't see very often on our site.

Comment: DVK used to cite a lot of Russian-language sources when he was active here.

Answer (score 1):

I would nominate this [answer](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/15408/8723) by [Eddie Kal](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/2500/eddie-kal). The reason I chose it because he has used a different of understanding those paragraphs, he tried to use the archaic meaning of the words (although Eliot was a modern poet) and came up with a very satisfying explanation. His semantic analysis was applaudable.