# Where can I find glossaries of literary, poetic and rhetorical terms?

Tags: support, faq-proposed

Many questions on Literature Stack Exchange ask about literary devices. Where can question askers (or answerers) find resources about literary, poetic and rhetorical terms?

Answer (score 3):

- [List of narrative techniques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_narrative_techniques) on Wikipedia.
- [Glossary of literary terms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_literary_terms) on Wikipedia.
- [Stylistic device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stylistic_device) on Wikipedia.
- [Poetic devices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poetic_devices) on Wikipedia.
- [Rhetorical device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetorical_device) on Wikipedia.
- [Glossary of Poetic Terms](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/learn/glossary-terms) by Poetry Foundation.
- [Literary Terms and Definitions](http://web.cn.edu/kwheeler/lit_terms.html): a glossary compiled by L. Kip Wheeler, professor of composition and literature at Carson-Newman University.
- [LiteraryTerms.net](https://literaryterms.net/).
- [Literary Devices & Terms](https://www.litcharts.com/literary-devices-and-terms) by LitCharts.
- [Literary Devices and Terms](https://literarydevices.net/) on LiteraryDevices.net.
- [Lexique des termes littéraires](http://www.lettres.org/lexique/index.htm): a glossary on Lettres.org, a website dedicated to the study and the teaching of French.
- [Algemeen letterkundig lexicon](https://dbnl.org/tekst/dela012alge01_01/index.php) (in Dutch).